# Calling API multiple times - Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to use an API that converts dates. I've retrieved data from a file that contained full dates, used split and slice to get the day, month and year seperately. I need to send each date and return the conversion to the user.

What I currently have is:

```
def convert(day, month, year):
        gr_to_hb_url = 'https://www.hebcal.com/converter?cfg=json&gy='+ year+ '&gm='+ month+ '&gd='+ day+'&g2h=1'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(gr_to_hb_url) as response:
            data = response.read()
            obj = json.loads(data)
            
            results = [(result['hd'], result['hm'],result['hy']) for result in obj]
            return results
```

```
hby, hbm, hbd=convert(prep_day, prep_month, prep_year)
print(hby,hbm,hbd)
```

prep_day/ month/ year are the day, month and year I retrieved from each day separately as I mentioned above.

The error I get TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I wager than the contense of result is of type string

Comment: are you sure each result in obj is a `dict`? From the error trace, it looks like they are `lists` and you are trying to index them as `dict`, using a key.

Comment: @Shandron why not use `requests`? it becomes a little easier that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the output of the request:

```
{"gy":2020,"gm":1,"gd":1,"afterSunset":false,"hy":5780,"hm":"Tevet","hd":4,"hebrew":"ד׳ בְּטֵבֵת תש״פ","events":["Parashat Vayigash"]}
```

I think you might want the following instead:

```
def convert(day, month, year):
        gr_to_hb_url = 'https://www.hebcal.com/converter?cfg=json&gy='+ year+ '&gm='+ month+ '&gd='+ day+'&g2h=1'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(gr_to_hb_url) as response:
            data = response.read()
            obj = json.loads(data)
            
            results = (obj['hd'], obj['hm'],obj['hy'])
            return results
```

The reason for the error you were seeing was that when you iterate through a dictionary type you just get the values.
In this case that would be something like the following (Although the order isn't guaranteed when iterating through a dictionary)
[2020,1,1,False, ...]
I imagine that the first element that you were iterating through was something like "Tevet".
If the value of result is "Tevet" then running `"Tevet"["hd"]`
would result in the error you were seeing.